# How can one transform a data table using data.table

Tags: r, group-by, data.table, aggregate

I would like to transform following data table

```
da<-data.table(Gr=c("A","B","B","B","A","B"),
   mmoSze=c("SCRSCR","SCRSCR","OSNOSN","Eig.SCRSCR","Eig.SCRSCR","Eig.OSNOSN"),
              SCR=c(25, 43, 61, 79, 97, 115))
```

into:

```
da.goal<-data.table(GR=c(   "A",    "B"),
SCRSCR=c(   25, 43),
OSNOSN=c(   0,  61),
Eig.SCRSCR=c(   97, 79),
Eig.OSNOSN=c(   0,  115))
```

using `data.table`!
One possible undesirable way would be to divide the table and then merge them. What is the elegant way to do it?

Comment: you have the `melt` function to transform from wide to long format, and `dcast` to transform from long to wide. See https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-reshape.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`dcast()` is a `data.table` function, and I think this is elegant enough:

```
dcast(da, Gr ~ mmoSze)
```

Only problem is that you get `NA` instead of `0`, but then you can do:

```
res = dcast(da, Gr ~ mmoSze)
res[is.na(res)] <- 0
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert your long table to wide:

```
dcast(da, Gr ~ mmoSze, fill = 0)
```

`fill = 0` will put a zero where it can't find a value.